# How to connect with username/password to mongodb using native node.js driver

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native, joyent

I'm using native mongo driver in Joyent cloud, the node.js application runs fine locally but in Joyent when I run with the username/password that they provided it fails to connect.

This is the code I use to connect:

```
var db = new MongoDB(dbName, new Server('localhost', 27017 , {auto_reconnect: true}), {w: 1});
db.open(function(e, db){
if (e) {
    console.log(e);
} else{
    console.log('connected to database :: ' + dbName);
    //db.admin().authenticate('admin', '+(uihghjk', function(de , db){
    // if(e){
    //     console.log("could not authenticate");
    // }else {
    //console.log('connected to database :: ' + dbName);
    // }
    // });
}
});
```

What's stopping me from connecting successfully?

Comment: The above commented code works fine for authentication. 
The problem was they mixed up with credentials provided for mongodb,
to verify login and password, ssh to joyent and enter $(mdata-get mongodb_pw), verify the given pswd works in
"mongo -uadmin -p$(mdata-get mongodb_pw) admin"

Answer (score 50):

Easier if you just use MongoClient

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/db', function (err, db) {
```

Comment: This is very correct, but how can I hide the credentials from the repository? is there a way to use a hash key or something like that?

Comment: @Mavro in one project with mongoose I see the whole path with credentials stored in a config file which is not committed to repository, then variable used in connect.

Answer (score 9):

**the working code would be like this**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-saugt.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
    // creating collection
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
    // perform actions on the collection object
    client.close();
});
```

Comment: In order to leverage the DNS seed list, use a connection string prefix of `mongodb+srv` [as explained](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#dns-seed-list-connection-format)

Answer (score 6):

Standard URI connection scheme is:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

For Example:

```
mongodb://admin:pass@abc.com/
```

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 2):

Use `<username> : <password>` right after `//` in the URL.

I am using Mongoose to connect and my username and password is admin admin

```
mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.c1xrp
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including [another well-received answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52288654/14267427).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
`mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<dbname>?authSource=admin`
```