# connect to mongodb when you have Google login as credentials for Mongodb Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have google Atlas account, which is using my google credentials to login. What password should I use to connect to the DB from my NodeJS application (not specific to NodeJS, but any application) when I have google credentials as login credentials.

This is my connection string, what should I use in password?

```
mongodb+srv://kushalseth:<password>@node.zzzzzz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I don't want to impact the google login for my atlas account as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16124255/4393351

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do here is :

1. Open your project in Atlas.
2. In the Security section, go to Database Access. Click on the edit option for the current user. Change your password and click on 'Update User' and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lots of things to connect to mongodb using google login. but finally found an alternative. In this way I retained my gmail login and got a user and password to connect using the url.

I went to Atlas at https://cloud.mongodb.com/,

- I opened my Project in Atlas, and opened Database Access.
- In Database Access, I have created a new User, and gave it all the admin rights and there I found the option to provide password for this new user.

[image]